# All URLs Redirect to Main Page

Tags: redirect, login

Whenever I try to access pages within my site, such as mysite.com/wp-login.php, it redirects to mysite.com. It doesn't redirect if I put www.mysite.com, however. Is this a domain configuration issue, or a WordPress issue?

Comment: Check your `.htaccess` file in the wp root (or below) dir.

Comment: I don't see one anywhere.

Comment: What changed to cause this behavior?  That will be your best starting point for debug.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is that you haven't generated permalinks/a proper .htaccess file for your site. From within Wordpress, go to Settings > Permalinks, and update/save your link structure. See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this I think it should work for you

```
http://example.com/your-sub-dir/wp-login.php
```

I had a similar problem where I couldn't login it looks like you're just missing the `your-sub-dir` part in the URl. I think the problem may be in your `wp-login.php` file if that gets you into admin great if not let me know and I'll give you a few more ways you can try to get in.

If you can get in try this.  Go to the case `retrievepassword` section, found under this comment:

```
// redefining user_login ensures we return the right case in the email
// Replace: 
$user_login = $user_data["user_login"];

// With: 
$user_login = $user_data->user_login;
```